# Is it my ABS sensors that are bad on a 95 Safari Van?

Tags: brakes, mil, abs, awd

When I drive on snowy roads, the brakes lock up nicely.  When I brake on dry roads, the van hops all over the place when I brake.. to the point I feel like the front end is going to fall off.  Could this be an ABS problem?  The light has been on for years, but this just started happening when we drove it again this winter.  It is full time AWD.

Thanks for any direction you can give me!

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to pull the ABS codes. That will give us a starting point for trouble shooting.

This model supports flash codes, you will need to jump across terminal A and H of the ALDL connector (under the drivers side of the dash). It may take about 30 seconds before the ABS light starts flashing codes.

[image]

Count the flashes to get the code, they repeat 3 times if I remember correctly.

Edit your question to include the codes you get, I have listed the codes below for reference, but will continue to help you once you let me know what the codes are.

The list of codes follow

Code 21-RF speed sensor or circuit open

Code 22-Missing RF speed signal

Code 23-Erratic RF speed sensor

Code 25-LF speed sensor or circuit open

Code 26-Missing LF speed signal

Code 27-Erratic LF speed sensor

Code 29-Simultaneous drop out of front speed sensors

Code 31-RR speed sensor or circuit open

Code 32-Missing RR speed signal

Code 33-Erratic RR speed signal

Code 35-VSS or LR speed sensor or circuit open

Code 36-Missing VSS or LR speed sensor or circuit open

Code 37-Erratic VSS or LR speed sensor signal

Code 38-Wheel speed error

Code 41-54-Control valves

Code 61-63-Reset switches

Code 65-66-Open or shorted pump motor relay

Code 67-Open motor circuit or shorted BPMV output

Code 68-Locked motor or shorted motor circuit

Code 71-74-Memory errors

Code 81-Brake switch circuit shorted or open

Code 86-Shorted anti-lock indicator lamp

Code 88-Shorted brake warning lamp